# How to get values from ng-repeat in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list">
</div>
```

This obj is having 6 properties like name, country, state, city, street, and contact. I have written following code for this but it is giving me undefined as the value if i try to fetch the stored value in obj.

```
var elm = element.all(by.repeater('obj in list'));

elm.then(function(obj){
    console.log("Number of Rows : "+ rows.length);
    for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++){
         console.log("App name : " + rows[i].name);
    }
});
```

This is printing "App name : undefined" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are using promises so you can't log a unresolved promise. All executions in Protractor are promises. 
Secondly, you are using the `rows`, but you never defined it. Is `rows` the same as `obj`?

Third, try to avoid the a `for` loop with Promises. It's better to use for example the [each](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) from protractor. If you do that your code looks like this

```
var elm = element.all(by.repeater('obj in list'));
elm.each(function(obj, index) {
  // Will print 0 First, 1 Second, 2 Third.
  obj.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(index, text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, the ng-repeat does not contain an object, it contains a list. in your case, an array.
if you have nested lists (ng-repeat in ng-repeat) please specify that in your question. otherwise, the following code should work for you.

```
let elm = element.all(by.repeater('obj in list'));

elm.getText().then(function(text){
console.log(text);
});
```